# How fast should you rotate a chain hoop so that it doesn't tilt?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque, rotation, special-functions

[image]

Consider spinning a closed chain as in the figure above, I want the speed at which the chain will be kept in a horizontal plane. Inspired by this [irodov question](http://irodovsolutionsmechanics.blogspot.com/2008/05/irodov-problem-1145.html)

Considering taking the point where the chain and rope are pivoted, if we compute torque around there on all mass elements then we can say:

$$ I_{net} \alpha = \int  \vec{r_i} \times \vec{dmg} \vec{k}$$

Where,$ \vec{r_i} \times \vec{dmg} \vec{k}$ is the torque produced by one small mass element on the chain where $\vec{r_i}$ is the point from pivot to that element

Or,

$$I_{net} \alpha = g\int  dm (\vec{r} \times \vec{k}) $$

For, a circular hoop, the inertia given as $ I_{net} = \frac{Mr^2}{2}$

Hence,

$$ \alpha = \frac{2g}{Mr^2} \int  dm (\vec{r} \times \vec{k})$$

I'm not sure how to evaluate the integral. However, is there any way to get qualitative conclusions without the equations?

I've drawn the arrows below to show an illustration of how it is rotating:

[image]

To put short: basically, the way it wants to fall naturally

**I do understand that there will be always a tendency for the chain to keep tilting but is there any way to make the tilting negligible**?

---

Alternate methods:

I saw a video about how rotating chains are related to Bessel functions, so I am wondering if we can use that here refer 12:55 of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CU1f2cnOfok&list=PLKc2XOQp0dMwj9zAXD5LlWpriIXIrGaNb&index=5&ab_channel=PennOnlineLearning).

Comment: What do you mean by "negligible"? You can make the tilt angle arbitrarily small by increasing the rate of rotation. Unless you state how small you want the tilt angle to be, your question cannot be answered.

Comment: Basically I want to figure out the functional dependencies so that I can minimize tilting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segments of chain in the loop are subject to tension forces from each side. The resultant of these must have a radial component which provides the centripetal acceleration, and a vertical component which supports the weight (except at the point of support where the vertical component of the cord supports all of the weight).  With a higher angular velocity, the tensions increase, and the angle of tilt gets smaller (but never zero).

Comment: Perfect explanation thank you!

Comment: On second thought, having a bit of difficulty visualizing how the tension forces varies along the boundary.. A picture would be helpful, but regardless I understood the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Havent actually done any calculation as I think it would be perfectly horizontal to where the 'force' outwards is infinite. T there will always be a vector component of force pointing vectially downwards due to gravity that would result in the net vector to be non horizontal for any finite horizontal 'force'